# tsconfig setup for renamed node modules directory

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

I have a situation where I have a `node_modules` directory named `node_modules_copy` (that I **cannot** change to `node_modules`) that I'd like to effectively replace/use as the default `node_modules` for typing information in my tsconfig.json. I attempted to solve this like so:

```json
// tsconfig.json

{
  "paths": { "*": ["./node_modules_types/@types/*", "./node_modules_types/*"] }
}
```

This resolves all of the typing errors except for my images. For example, I now see a new error that I did not get before if it were looking at `node_modules`:

```
import logo from '../assets/logo.png';
// error: Cannot find module '../assets/logo.png' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I've found some suggestions elsewhere, but I'd like to understand why this error arises when I simply point to a different node modules directory.

Is there a way to point to a new node modules directory without getting this typing error about png files? Normally typescript would detect the png module automatically

Comment: I'm quite sure this is due to typescript only resolving ts/mts/cts files by default. Depending on the configuration, it might resolve js/mjs/cjs, json and the react variants (tsx/jsx). For all other file extensions I'd expect you'd need to add a dts file exposing the extension as a module.

Comment: Thanks for your response @pascalpuetz. Declaring the png module in png.d.ts fixes this, but can you explain why this works by default when I don't have node modules in a different location? Edit: this import is in a react tsx file